# Sci-Kit learn KBinsDicretizer produces different shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I require equal width discretization of the attributes to the dataset and then continue with plotting values dataset discretized vs continous. for that I need complete discrete valued dataset and not a sparse matrix

```
X,y = datasets[0]
enc = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=5 )
X_binned = enc.fit_transform(X)
print(pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X_binned).shape)
print(X.shape)
```

Output:

```
(100, 10)
(100, 2)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`KBinsDiscretizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html) default encoding method is `onehot`, meaning that the transformed result will be the OneHot encoded columns obtained from each feature.

You can set the encoding to `ordinal` so that each bin is encoded as an integer value, and hence the shape is preserved:

```
enc = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=5, encode='ordinal')
X_binned = enc.fit_transform(x)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, can you please give the reason? If I'm not wrong onehotencoding is to convert categorical values to discrete values for classifiers to work with. Then why was it producing a shape of num_attributes*bins

Comment: [OneHotEncoders](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) transform a categorical variable into *n* new columns, one for each category the feature takes @aijax